# Why sometimes Matlab saves figures with wrong colors?

Tags: matlab

Why sometimes Matlab saves figures with wrong colors?

This is the code: http://pastebin.com/V50B9TSc

Basically for plotting I use the commands plot and scatter.

For example, look at this image. Those points are actually colored,
they are colored in Matlab, but once I save that as .png image, the points lose color.

[image]

and this is the original:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: *If* you save it through a script, please provide the code.

Comment: Nope, I save from the plot window.

Comment: By the way, I edited my original post, you can compare the two images in terms of colors.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example how you plot dots and background or give us AT LEAST the commands you use? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original post with the code guys. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the background blending is messing with color of the points. How are you drawing the background?

A quick way of not having to worry about the color would be to use different makers for the two point sets.

EDIT: (also try saving as a jpg. If my hypothesis is correct the background might be weird but the points should have the right color)

Comment: I don't see why changing the markers would fix the colors problem.

Comment: Changing the markers would not solve the problem, it would avoid it. If the jpg is the same, it's not a blending problem. can you post your plotting code?

Comment: Just edited my original post, please check out the code. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sorry can't reproduce ... plotted with your code using a gradient for Z ... saved using the window button Here is the result I get  [result](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/153/86493170.png/)

Comment: still can't reproduced tried Win7 x64 matlab R2012a and Debian same matlab version...sorry

Comment: Yes weird, I tried the same code on another 64-bit machine and it works fine. For some reason on my 32-bit laptop and Matlab 2012b I can't save properly.